# posting notification to multiple observers

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnotificationcenter

I need a detail tutorial about posting notification to multiple observers.
Here is my code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

{

 NSString *notificationName = @"MT";

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(useNotificationWithString:)
                                              name:notificationName
                                            object:nil];

}
```

This  is for the current object I want to post notification to the objects of other class too.

Comment: If you are able to do this much. You just need to post a desire notification as originating part.

Answer (score 3):

You don't post a notification to multiple objects. Instead, you have multiple objects watch for a notification, then when you want them all to receive that notification, you post it to the notification center. The notification center does the work of informing the observing objects.

Answer (score 1):

Add same observer for each object where you want to receive notification. Then post notification somewhere and all your observers will receive it. Don't forget to call `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self]` in `-(void)dealloc` or in `-(void)viewDidUnload` methods of each object.

Answer (score 1):

**You never post a notification to multiple observers, infact observers observe your notifications.**

You post a notification once with a notification name.

And add **OBSERVER in all the classes** that will observe for the posted notification.

Each of your class that you want to observe will have following :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(useNotificationWithString:)
                                              name:notificationName
                                            object:nil];
```

You can get [full notes here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i) in Apple Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should add these code in each class each class who wishes to receive notifications.

And use next code for post notification for all objects:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MT" object:self]
```